Is there any stack trace using WASM?
I recently came across WASM. I am very hopeful about the potential that it can do on the server side. But One thing I did not understand.
Let's say I write an app in python and then convert it to WASM and deploy it. Or in any other language and convert to WASM for that matter. If there is any error comes on the server side, does it give me the stack trace of where the error occurred? How do I fix and deploy it then ? If I can not get the stack trace, does not it make it useless?

You could just as well ask "is there any stack trace in x86 assembly?" or "is there any stack trace in MIPS?" -- stack traces aren't inherent to the instruction set or bytecode; often, even stacks aren't inherent to an instruction set. That said, any Python implementation for WASM that didn't support stack traces wouldn't be much of a Python implementation.

If the logs include memory addresses, use tools like llvm-dwarfdump or source maps to correlate these to your original code.

As for py2wasm specifically -- yes, it supports stack traces. But you need to ask at that level; it's not a generic webassembly question.

@CharlesDuffy: It could be any language; not just python. If there is no stack trace. how to iterate? If you do not know where is the error. what is the point. As for x86 assembly, people do not write x86 now a days. People write in higher level languages for obvious benefits, one of which is stack trace.

Sorry, My question did not seem generic earlier but I was intending to. I have edited it.

Right, but WASM is like x86 -- it's a low-level instruction set. People build high-level things (including tools for exporting stack traces) on top of it. But just because people build stack traces on top of x86 machine instructions doesn't mean that x86 machine instructions have stack trace support built in. In exactly the same way, it's unreasonable to expect WASM to have stack trace support built in -- that's not its job, it's the job of layers built on top of it. And that's why I say the question is unreasonable and unanswerable: it's asking about the wrong layer in the stack.

x86 remains relevant here as an example for comparison because your high-level languages (with features like stack traces) boil down to x86 instructions when that's the platform you're running on, just like they boil down to WASM when that's the platform you're running on. Does that help it make more sense now? Your question is exactly like asking "is there any stack trace using x86?", and it's not a question that makes any sense: x86 doesn't provide stack traces any more than WASM does; they don't need innate support, it's the job of higher layers.

(I'm glossing over some things -- the WebAssembly spec is aware of call frames, which in x86 is more the job of an individual ABI built on top, making it easier to implement stack traces in WASM -- but the general point holds).
